# Laravel Blade @php directive not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

After updated my `Ubuntu to 17.10`, `PHP to 7.2.3`, and created a fresh Laravel project with version `5.6.12`, I've tested this blade code:

```
@php($x = 5)
@php $y = 2 @endphp
```

and get this output from browser

```
<?php($x = 5)
@php $y = 2 ?>
```

Is it a bug or the `@php` bracket directive has been deprecated?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Either close first `@php` too or remove second `@php`

Comment: I think you need to try like this: `@php($x = 5) @endphp
@php $y = 2 @endphp` OR `@php($x = 5) $y = 2 @endphp`

Comment: ok got it. actually direct @php() without @endphp working before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are starting `@php` in `@php($x = 5)` but forgot to close. Do it like:

```
@php
$x = 5
@endphp
@php 
$y = 2
@endphp
```

OR

You may have not necessary to re-open `@php` in line 2. Like:

```
@php
$x = 5
$y = 2 
@endphp
```

Comment: can you please edit saying @php() not working anymore. i'm positive it's working before

Comment: `@php` working and it'll also defined in docs of L5.6: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#php

Comment: i mean php() with bracket without endphp. never mind let's conclude this. thank you for the answer

Comment: If you are starting `@php` then you need to end it like `@endphp` as we do in core PHP. We start the `<?php` and end it like: `?>` It's compulsory!!

Comment: @jerinho is absolutely correct, the @php() single line directive (just like the @include() directive) used to work! I can't find anywhere stating that it was deprecated and I'm really frustrated too. This is the only thread I've found about the issue. Thanks for asking!

Comment: as I've been told. single line @php directive actually is a bug on previous version of blade. as the bug had been removed now we have to fix our code. thank god mine only a few

Comment: @isabisa yes, it's fixed in new version. If this answer helps you, you can upvote it!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
@php ($x = 5) @endphp
@php $y = 2 @endphp
```

But I prefer the clasic one, PHP,  it is almost the same characters and blade does not have to work behind.

```
<?php 
$x = 5;
$y = 2;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use

```
@php($x=0)
```

without closing it will work in Laravel 8 and Laravel 9

Comment: But not in Laravel 10... :)